# Unable to send sequence of values from Client to server

Tags: vb.net

HI unable to send sequence of values from client to server as the client window exits once after entering two input values.
Please find the client code below:

```
 Sub Main()
    Dim connection = New HubConnection("http://localhost:8080")

    Dim myHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("myHub")

    connection.Start().Wait()
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow
    myHub.Invoke(Of String)("Chatter", Console.ReadLine) _
    .ContinueWith(
        Sub(task)
            If task.IsFaulted Then
                Console.WriteLine("Could not Invoke the server method Chatter: {0}", _
                                  task.Exception.GetBaseException())
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("Success calling chatter method")
            End If
        End Sub)

    myHub.On(Of String)("addMessage", _
        Sub(param)
            Console.WriteLine("Client receiving value from server: {0}", param.ToString())
        End Sub)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

i tried using while loop but endedup in some errors could anyone please help.
Posted it again as i couldn't find the right solution.

Comment: Is the 2 value an _input value_ and not the input for last readline? I do not see any loop around `Invoke`...

Comment: Isn't that the same as your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39895571/unable-to-send-more-than-two-input-values-using-a-while-loop

Comment: Yes i mentioned why i posted

Comment: yes there is no loop in the code i posted this is the initial structure i have