# Console App Listen to response from Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, console-application

At the moment I have 2 projects. One is my bot which is a console application, which sends messages to my slack channel and listens into it. My second project is an .net `MVC` application which listens to post request incoming from slack.

A typical round of communication would be the user typing play!

The bot would pick up play! and then it would send an interactive message with buttons. When the buttons are pressed, it sends a post request to my .net `MVC` application which is deployed to azure.

I'm a little stuck at the moment. How do I get the web application to send a notification to my console application to simple begin the game?

At the moment when an interactive button is clicked and my `MVC` app registers it, the `MVC` application will make an entry into the database. My bot application is busy querying every 5 seconds to see if there's an entry in the database to play the game. A better solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I may not be understanding correctly. But in you `MVC` application's `[POST]` method, could you just return a message to your Console Application to trigger the start of the game?

Comment: That's the question @FarzanMirheydari how would you return the message to the console app?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) on your ASP.NET application.

> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes
>   developing real-time web functionality easy. SignalR allows
>   bi-directional communication between server and client. Servers can
>   now push content to connected clients instantly as it becomes
>   available. SignalR supports Web Sockets, and falls back to other
>   compatible techniques for older browsers. SignalR includes APIs for
>   connection management (for instance, connect and disconnect events),
>   grouping connections, and authorization.

Basically, this is used for real-time notifications and chat applications.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12058856/6138713)'s a sample for consuming it in a console application.