# How to create a subscription on a specific SQL Server table when rows are added?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, .net-core

I have a back-end that synchronizes data from an ERP that's running in SQL Server.

I don't want to run `select * from table where [not have processed filter]` every second to catch new data.

When a new row is added to a specific table, I want to have some kind of event subscription that will cause my .NET Windows service to get this new data and just send it directly to the backend.

In the backend I already have a channel that receives the data and updates whoever is subscribed in the frontend.

I looked into Event Notification that exists since SQL Server 2016 but it doesn't look like what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Triggers on insert. You have to configure the connections between your data sources. Make sure to test your triggers thoroughly

Comment: Which is might be a license violation if the ERP is not developed internally.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use SignalR, these are samples can be useful:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140164/signalr-console-app-example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr)

[SignalR-example2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr)