# you are using a version of the client that isn't compatible with the server SignalR Console

Tags: c#, signalr

I am trying to create a console app with SignalR communication.

I have tried [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12058856/17450256), I followed the steps and I recive the following error:

> There was an error opening the connection:System.InvalidOperationException: You are using a version of the client that isn't compatible with the server. Client version 2.1, server version 1.0.

The error occures at client side.

I am using .NET Framework 4.7.2

any suggesions?

NOTE that's a console app not a web app so I don't have `web.config` file

Comment: I would start with getting your SignalR versions in sync.

Comment: What version of SignalR are you using?  The latest for .NET Framework is 2.4.2.  What kind of client (JS, .NET, etc.) are you using?

Comment: If you are able to use .NET 5/6, you should do so as the .NET Framework SignalR will no longer be actively developed.